# if : $-10<x<+10\\-70<y<+50\\x+y=40$ then : What is the range $xy$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if :

$$-10<x<+10\\-70<y<+50\\x+y=40$$

then : What is the range $xy$?

my try :

$$|x|<10\\|y|<70\\x^2<(10^2)\\y^2<(70)^2\\x^2+y^2<(10)^2+(70)^2\\(x+y)^2-2xy<(10)^2+(70)^2\\ \frac{(40)^2-(10)^2-(70)^2}{2}<xy$$

is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

To have $xy$ maximal with a given sum you want $x=y$.  Here we can't have that because of the restriction on $x$, so the greatest product we can get is $x=10,y=30,xy=300$.  The most negative product we can get is $x=-10,y=50, xy=-500$, so $$-500 \le xy \le 300$$
You can plot a graph of $xy=x(40-x)$ over the range allowed.
[image]

Comment: There is also $x=10, y=-50$ for the lower bound, and note that the inequalities in the question are strict.